# How to drag and limit canvas border in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-controls, simulation

My WPF app is simulating a map, using Shapes (Rectangles and Lines). For comfortable using I should add zooming and dragging map.

This is my XAML code:

```
<Border Margin="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Canvas Grid.Column="0" x:Name="mainCanvas" Background="Transparent" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

I wrote working code for zomming:

```
int zoom = 1;

private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;
    var position = e.GetPosition(element);
    var transform = (MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform;
    var matrix = transform.Matrix;

    if(e.Delta >= 0)
    {
        if (zoom <= 10)
        {
            zoom++;
            matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1, 1.1, position.X, position.Y);
            transform.Matrix = matrix;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (zoom > 1)
        {
            zoom--;
            matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(1.0/1.1, 1.0 / 1.1, position.X, position.Y);
            transform.Matrix = matrix;
        }
    }
}
```

I faced with problem: when I`m zooming my canvas, canvas go beyond border. Moreover, I hae no idea how to drag canvas. So, also I want to move my map (canvas) when I moving mouse down. How can I make it?

I tried to use PanAndZoom cotrol from NuGet, but it didnt work (I can`t even add to my form in XAML). Maybe because of I use .Net 7.

Comment: *"canvas go beyond border"* - What does that mean? You can limit the zoom total factor (e.g., only allow 5x magnification).  Regarding panning, you probably want to use scroll bars. Otherwise, you would have to extend the Canvas and override Arrange (or/and implement IScrollInfo). You have to move hidden elements into view and previously visible elements out of view. A ScrollViewer does this for you.  You can programmatically scroll with the ScrollViewer too. Just set the e.g. ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset property based on the mouse position (obtained in the MouseMove event handler)

Comment: You can even make the scroll bars very tiny so that they become invisible and only control them programmatically.